# Want to Return Empty Rows With a Case When Statement

Tags: sql

Lets say I'm using 2 case when statements to group my data, like in the below example:

```
select case 
    when group1 = 'A' then 'Large'
    when group1 = 'B' then 'Medium'
    else 'Small' 
end as 'Order Size'
,case 
    when method = 'Delivery' then 'Delivery'
    else 'Pick-up' 
end as 'Distribution Method'
,count(distinct(OrderIDs)) 
from OrderTable
GROUP BY 
select case 
    when group1 = 'A' then 'Large'
    when group1 = 'B' then 'Medium'
    else 'Small' 
end
,case 
    when method = 'Delivery' then 'Delivery'
    else 'Pick-up' 
end
```

Lets also say that there were no "Large" deliveries that were "Pick-Up'. Currently, this query will not return a row with Large,PickUp category.

Is there a way to have a row returned with 0’s if there is nothing that meets the multiple case when criteria?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and `left join` to bring in the data:

```
select os.OrderSize, coalesce(d.DistributionMethod, 'Pick-Up') as 
        count(*)
from (select 'Large' as OrderSize union all
      select 'Medium' as OrderSize union all
      select 'Small' as OrderSize
     ) os cross join
     (select 'Delivery' as DistributionMethod union all
      select 'Pick-Up' as DistributionMethod
    ) d left join
    OrderTable ot
    on ( (ot.group1 = 'A' and os.OrderSize = 'Large') or
         (ot.group1 = 'B' and os.OrderSize = 'Medium') or
         (ot.group1 not in ('A', 'B') and os.OrderSize = 'Small') 
       ) and
       ot.method = d.DistributionMethod     
group by os.OrderSize, coalesce(d.DistributionMethod, 'Pick-Up');
```

Not all databases support the creation of a table of constants using this syntax, but there is generally some syntax that does this.

Answer (score 0):

You could select a recordset that contains the required values and then left join your grouped recordset from there.  Following is an example for SQL Server where you would join your results to `[Groupings].[OrderSize]` and `[Groupings].[DistributionMethod]`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT 'Large' AS [OrderSize]
        UNION
        SELECT 'Medium' AS [OrderSize]
        UNION
        SELECT 'Small' AS [OrderSize]
    )     AS [OrderSizes]
        CROSS JOIN (
            SELECT 'Delivery' AS [DistributionMethod]
            UNION
            SELECT 'Pick-up' AS [DistributionMethod]
        ) AS [DistributionMethods]
) AS [Groupings]
    LEFT JOIN ...
```